# Does the norm of a (1,1) tensor depend on the conformal factor?

Tags: differential-geometry, solution-verification, riemannian-geometry, tensors

If we have a $(1,1)$ tensor $T$ on a (pseudo-)Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$, its norm is
$$
g(T, T) = g_{AB}g^{CD}T^A_C T^B_D.
$$
If we let $h = \phi^2 g$ be a conformally equivalent metric, then its inverse is $h^{-1} = \phi^{-2}g^{-1}$ and thus the norm of $T$ as measured by $h$ is identical, as the conformal factors cancel out. This only happens when $T$ is a mixed tensor which is covariant in the same number of indices as it is contravariant.

Questions: Is this proof correct? Is there any geometric reason why these types of tensors have their norm preserved by conformal transformations?

Comment: The (1,1) tensors can be seen as linear maps. I think that a good interpretation of the phenomenon you observed should use this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proof is correct. Giuseppe Negro's comment about $(1,1)$-tensors being regarded as linear maps is also right on point. The same works for $(r,r)$-tensors, as $$h_{i_1j_1}\cdots h_{i_rj_r}h^{k_1\ell_1}\cdots h^{k_r\ell_r} T^{i_1\cdots i_r}_{\qquad k_1\cdots k_r}T^{j_1\cdots j_r}_{\qquad \ell_1\cdots \ell_r} = g_{i_1j_1}\cdots g_{i_rj_r}g^{k_1\ell_1}\cdots g^{k_r\ell_r} T^{i_1\cdots i_r}_{\qquad k_1\cdots k_r}T^{j_1\cdots j_r}_{\qquad \ell_1\cdots \ell_r}, $$since cancellations happen in pairs. Linear algebra: a multilinear map $(V^*)^{\times r} \times V^{\times r} \to \Bbb R$ can be seen as a linear map $V^{\otimes r} \to V^{\otimes r}$, so there you have it. If the quantity of covariant indices is not equal to the quantity of contravariant indices, you'll have extra $V$ or $V^*$ factors which will break the conformal invariance.

Comment: In this spirit, and Gisueppe Negro's comment, is the reason I should expect the norm of a linear map $T$ to be conformally invariant just because the operator norm on the normed vector space each metric induces is the same if we scale the norm by a constant factor?

Comment: Yes, exactly. The thing is that an inner product in $V$ induces an inner product in $V^*$ (the components of the induced inner product in $V^*$ are $g^{ij}$) and also an inner product in ${\rm Hom}(V,V)$. The isomorphism ${\rm Hom}(V,V) \cong V^*\otimes V$ turns out to be an isometry. Another comment that might be enlightening: given a bilinear $B\colon V \times V \to \Bbb R$, of course one can think of it as $\widetilde{B}\colon V \to V$ via $B(v,w) = g(\widetilde{B}(v),w)$, but $B \mapsto \widetilde{B}$ depends on the inner product, while ${\rm Hom}(V,V) \cong V^*\otimes V$ does not.